# Linear Algebra Basis and redundancy

Tags: linear-algebra

I need help understanding how to do this problem:

> Consider $P_3$, let $A = \{a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4\}$ where \begin{align}a_1&=1-x+2x^2+x^3\\
> a_2&=2+x-2x^2-x^3\\
> a_3&=4-x+2x^2+x^3\\
> a_4&=4+5x-10x^2-5x^3\end{align}
>
> *Hint: Use $S=\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$*
>
> Find a set $B$ such that $B$ is a subset of $A$ and $B$ is a basis for $\text{span}(A)$.
>
> Find the dimension of $\text{span}(A)$.
>
> What are the redundancy equations for $A$ ?

Comment: What are your thoughts so far? People are more likely to help you if they can see what level you're at and what you already know

Comment: You just have to look if $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4$ are linear independent. They are not! Why?
Just stare. ;)

Comment: @Felix.C I don't buy that "just stare" is a viable method here

Comment: @user Please include some kind of context here, or your question will likely be closed. What are your thoughts? What have you tried? Do you know what is meant by the "coordinate vector of $a_1$ with respect to the basis $S$"? Do you know how to find the kernel/nullspace of a matrix?

Comment: I understand coordinate vectors, I do not know how to find the kernal/nullspace of a matrix. I'm not really sure where to start with this problem. The polynomials are confusing me, I'm just very lost on this.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom oh to stare at those equations is perfectly fine, but I tried to give a more detailed answer, but it's hard since we know few about his knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can see that $a_1 + a_1 + a_2 = a_3$ e.g. we can express $a_3$ as a linear combination of $a_1,a_2$, therefor they are not linear independent.

I'll leave this to you, but you can show with coefficient comparison that you can have $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a_4 = a*a_1 + b*a_2$

Also it's easy to see that $a_1$ is not a multiple of $a_2$!

As of you having trouble with this kind of exercise, I guess you don't know Gaussian elimination, but that would be the right way for similar exercises that aren't that "easy". Also you should read about rank of matrices.

What we know now is that span{$a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4$} = span{$a_1,a_2$} with {$a_1,a_2$} being a basis of A, since $a_1,a_2$ are linear independent --> Check the definition of a basis.

==> dim(A) = 2

Edit: Big mistake about the dimension fixed!

Comment: OH! Ok, I see now. So then a_3 and a_4 are redundant equations. Thanks so much, that explanation was very clear. I had to miss a couple weeks of class with some serious health issues and have been desperately trying to catch up, and long nights are turning my brain into mush.